# How to generate a Word document using Django

Tags: django

I'm new to Django and would like to create a form where users can input some data, and have a Word document be created for download.

I was using the templated-docs library (https://pypi.org/project/templateddocs/) to accomplish this task, but I'm receiving an error.

in my views.py:

```py
from templated_docs import fill_template
from templated_docs.http import FileResponse

def get_document(request):
    """
    A view to get a document filled with context variables.
    """
    context = {'user': request.user}  # Just an example

    filename = fill_template('sample.odt', context, output_format='pdf')
    visible_filename = 'greeting.pdf'

    return FileResponse(filename, visible_filename)
```

After the user inputs information in the form, I'm getting this error:

get_template_sources() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

the error is produced from the variable that's in views.py:
filename = fill_template('sample.odt', context, output_format='pdf')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The library was written 3 years back and no longer seems to be maintained.
It used LibreOffice via `pylokit` for parsing source and generating output.

Alternatively you can use [Pandoc](https://pypi.org/project/pypandoc/) (universal document converter) + [Pandoc Filters](https://pandoc.org/filters.html) for parsing source, doing modifications and generating output.

The whole of the above code can be accomplished with something like below.

```py
import io
import pypandoc
import panflute as pf
from django.http import FileResponse


def generate_invoice(request):
    template = 'files/invoice.docx'
    output_path = '/tmp/invoice - {}.pdf'.format(request.user.id)
    context = {
        '{{name}}': 'Foo'
    }

    # parse input file
    data = pypandoc.convert_file(template, 'json')
    f = io.StringIO(data)
    doc = pf.load(f)

    # do replacements
    for key, value in context.items():
        doc = doc.replace_keyword(key, pf.Str(value))

    # generate output
    with io.StringIO() as f:
        pf.dump(doc, f)
        contents = f.getvalue()
        pypandoc.convert_text(contents, 'pdf', format='json', outputfile=output_path)

    return FileResponse(open(output_path, 'rb'), filename='invoice.pdf')
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! can I also use Pandoc to create a Word document from a Django form?

Comment: Pandoc supports HTML to DOC conversion, so it should be possible.

Comment: How would I stream the output instead of saving it to a file? Or is this not possible with `pypandoc`?